# Show that the operator is bounded in $L_p$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Consider the operator $C$, acting on functions $f$ on the unit circle $S^1 = \left\{ z \in \mathbb C \mid |z| = 1 \right\}$ by the rule
$$
   (Cf)(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z(1+0)}d\zeta \equiv \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to + 0}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z(1+\epsilon)}d\zeta, \quad |z| = 1.
$$
The task is to show that $C$ is a linear continuous operator in $L_p(S^1)$ for any $p \in (1,\infty)$.

I have no idea how to deal here with arbitrary $L_p$-functions, but for functions $f_c$, holomorphic in some neigborhood of $S^1$ with the Laurent expansion
$$
   f_c(z) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n z^n
$$ 
in this neighborhood the operator $C$ just takes the main part of the Laurent expansion with the sign "$-$":
$$
   (Cf_c)(z)=-\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{n=-1} c_n z^n,
$$
so $C$ is a linear bounded operator in the space of functions, holomorphic in some neighborhood of $S^1$ (fixed). But why this is also true for the space $L_p$, $p \in (1,\infty)$? I think that the question may be reformulated: if we consider the space of functions, holomorphic in some fixed neighborhood of the unit circle $S^1$ and the operator taking the main part of the Laurent expansion of these functions then this operator may be continuously continued to the space $L_p(S^1)$, $p \in (1,\infty)$.

Comment: The operator you describe is directly related to the Hilbert transform on the circle. Can you use the fact  that the Hilbert transform is bounded on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$?

Comment: @user103402 yes, it is related to the Hilbert transform by the Sokhotsky-Plemelj formulas in the case of Holder functions $f$, but why these formulas are also valid in the case of $L_p$ functions? I think that this can be obtained by the pass to the limit but to pass to the limit we need the statement I have posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $p=2$ first. Up to a constant factor, the Hilbert transform acts on $L^2$   by reversing the sings of Fourier coefficients $c_n$ with $n<0$.   To see this, recall that the transform sends harmonic functions to  conjugate harmonic functions, which implies that $\sum c_{n\in\mathbb Z} e^{in\theta}$ is sent to $-i\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} (\operatorname{sign}  n)  c_n e^{in\theta}$.

So, $f\mapsto \frac12(f-iHf)$ is the operator that kills off all terms with $n>0$, and leaves the terms with $n<0$ untouched. This is the operator you described. Since the Hilbert transform is bounded on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, so is this one.

Answer (score 0):

Now you want to show that the holomorphic functions are dense in $L_p$. That is enough, because a bounded linear operator in a dense set extends uniquely and continuously to the closure.

Comment: Thank you, I think that holomorphic on $S^1$ functions are dense in $L_p(S^1)$ because after the change of variables in the integral it follows from that trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L_p(0,2\pi)$. But I think it isn't enough to show that $C$ (defined by the integral) sends $L_p$ functions to $L_p$ functions. If it is shown then from the unicity of continuation we will obtain that $C$ is actually the continuation of the "taking the main part of the Laurent series" operator.

Comment: That is assuming one has an operator bound with respect to the $L^p$ norm, which hasn't been obtained yet.